# hover on single button in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

This javascript is used on the navbar on the following [page](http://vouzalis.com/test/test/)

When you hover the "blog" in the navbar, there is a dropdown coming, with a white background. The button "Test" should not be a dropdown, but I would like the same function as the blog button. So when you hover the button "test", there should come the same white background. At the moment the text is only becoming blue.

Does anybody have an idea how I can do that?

```
//Show dropdown on hover only for desktop devices
        //-----------------------------------------------
        var delay=0, setTimeoutConst;
        if ((Modernizr.mq('only all and (min-width: 768px)') && !Modernizr.touch) || $("html.ie8").length>0) {
            $('.main-navigation:not(.onclick) .navbar-nav>li.dropdown, .main-navigation:not(.onclick) li.dropdown>ul>li.dropdown').hover(
            function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
                    $this.addClass('open').slideDown();
                    $this.find('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('disabled');
                }, delay);

            },  function(){
                clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('disabled');
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with CSS using the following declaration:

```css
ul.nav.navbar-nav li:hover{
  background: white;
  }
```

:hover is a psuedo-class that detects a mouse over the element. You can learn more about the hover pseudo-class and others like it here: [Mozilla Developer Network CSS Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. That is working. So if I wanted the menu to stay white when is was active, I could do like this: 

`ul.nav.navbar-nav li:hover
ul.nav.navbar-nav li:active{ 
  background: white;
 }` Is that correct?

Comment: I believe you would need to put a comma between "li:hover" and the next element to be selected "ul.nav.navbar-nav".